# How to read .pb file using Google Colab?

Tags: tensorflow, colab, tensorboard

I would like to know how we can see/load/read a .pb file in Google Colab?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this snippet will help you.

```
import tensorflow as tf
model_path = "/PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE.pb"
model = tf.saved_model.load(model_path)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51278213/what-is-the-use-of-a-pb-file-in-tensorflow-and-how-does-it-work)